# jVectorMap get the value of the clicked region

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I have a jVectorMap created with the following code

```
var vmap = $('#world-map').vectorMap({
    regionsSelectable: true,
    regionsSelectableOne: true,
    series: {
        regions: [{
            scale: ['#cccccc', '#0A6EB4'],
            values: datasource
        }]
    },
    onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
        // if the value of the clicked region is ==1 do something 
    },
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    focusOn: {
        lat: -0.015, lng: 15,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        scale: 1.9
    }
});
```

where datasource is defined like this:

```
 countriesBgColors1 = {"AF": 1,"AL": 0,"DZ": 1,"AO": 0, ... }
```

The values are all 1 or 0. The data is retrieved using **AJAX**

In the function onRegionClick I'd like to execute the code only if the value of the clicked region is ==1, how can I do it?

It seems there is no way to retrieve it, unless I loop through the whole datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is simpler as You may think. No need to loop here, as You are receiving Your data as an object:

```
onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
    var countryData = countriesBgColors1[code];
    switch(countryData) {
      case 0:
        // do something
        break;
      case 1:
        // do something else
        break;
    }
},
```

As You are assigning Your data to the *map series regions*, the above code will be equivalent to:

```
onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
    var countryData = vmap.series.regions[0].values[code];
    switch(countryData) {
      case 0:
        // do something
        break;
      case 1:
        // do something else
        break;
    }
},
```

Hope this helps.